Macro to add page number in the body text of a MS word document
I am looking for a macro to add page numbers to every page of a word document (Previously, I implemented this approach that using a VBA code to add page numbers to the footer. I wanted to convert these page numbers in the footer to plain body text. this is the code but couldn't find a solution to convert it to plain text).
Sub PagetoFooter()
With ActiveDocument.Sections(1)
 .Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).PageNumbers.Add _
 PageNumberAlignment:=wdAlignPageNumberLeft, _
 FirstPage:=True
End With
End Sub


If you convert to plain text each page in the section will have the same number. Are you sure that is what you want?

Oh right, basically I want a macro to show my page numbers as plain text not in headers or footers. Do you have any idea how to do it?

Putting a page number in the main body is easy, just put it inside a text box. You’ll then need to add it to each page, which isn’t as easy as Word doesn’t really have a concept of pages. That’s why page numbers are added to headers or footers.

I know this one but can't follow this approach as textboxes are not supported where I have to import from Word. Looking for a way to add page numbers as body text without any text boxes.
So If you could help me to get a macro code to convert footer into plain text that would be a great help!?

Your only options are to use a text box or to create a style with a frame. Whatever your choice, you’ll also need to re-invent the wheel to ensure that page numbers are updated correctly, and deal with the inevitable issues that arise from the document being used with a different print driver. Are you still sure that you want to go this route?

I dont think so I should go this way. It will mess up and create more issues when I will try to import it from word. My main goal is to have page numbers as plain text

Then you need to edit your question and provide detailed instructions of precisely where the page number is to appear, and how it is to be formatted. You should also explain why you need to do this, not just for the benefit of those who decide to help you, but also for the benefit of future readers of your question.
